How to align specific children in a LazyColumn?
How can I align horizontally a particular children in a LazyColumn? it worked perfectly using Column, but it doesn't work in LazyColumn because I can't import Modifier.align for each particular item of the list, doesn't exist align import.
Column:
Column(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = column.getHorizontalAligment()
) {
    for (element in column.childs) {
        ElementComposableFactory(
            element = element,
            onClickAction = onClickAction,
            modifier = Modifier.align(element.getHorizontalAligment())
        )
    }
}

LazyColumn:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = column.getHorizontalAligment()
) {
    items(column.childs) { element ->
        ElementComposableFactory(
            element = element,
            onClickAction = onClickAction,
            modifier = Modifier.align(element.getHorizontalAligment()) <-- compilation error, align doesn't exist for the items of a lazycolumn
        )
    }
}


Well, finally I solved it using other approach:
Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()
     .wrapContentWidth(element.getHorizontalAligment())

That makes the aligment work correctly
LazyColumn(
    modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = column.getHorizontalAligment()
) {
    items(column.childs) { element ->
        ElementComposableFactory(
            element = element,
            onClickAction = onClickAction,
            modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth()
     .wrapContentWidth(element.getHorizontalAligment())
        )
    }
}


How about using Box() to wrap your ElementComposableFactory, something like this:
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentAlignment = Alignment.YourBoxContentAlignment) {
     ElementComposableFactory(
        element = element,
        onClickAction = onClickAction,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.YourElementAlignment)
    )
}


it gives exactly the same error

Hope I'm getting what you mean correctly. You can combine contentAlignment of the Box and Modifier.align of your Combosable to get the same result as HorizontalAligment

Like if you want your Composable completely in the center, you can set contentAlignment = Alignment.Center or  center but align to start: contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart, etc
